# How to upload a text file and parse contents into database in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So far I've managed to upload a file:

```
# In new.html.erb
<%= file_field_tag 'upload[file]' %>
```

And access the file in the controller

```
# In controller#create
@text = params[:upload][:file]
```

However, this gives me just the filename, not the file's contents. How do I access its contents?

I know this a jump, but once I can access the file's contents, would it all be possible to upload a folder and iterate through the files?

Answer (score 8):

### Complete Example

Take, for example, uploading an import file containing contacts. You don't need to store this import file, just process it and discard it.

#### Routes

**routes.rb**

```
resources :contacts do 
  collection do
    get 'import/new', to: :new_import  # import_new_contacts_path

    post :import                       # import_contacts_path
  end
end
```

#### Form

**views/contacts/new_import.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @contacts, url: import_contacts_path, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

  <%= f.file_field :import_file %>

<% end %>
```

#### Controller

**controllers/contacts_controller.rb**

```
def new_import
end

def import
  begin
    Contact.import( params[:contacts][:import_file] ) 

    flash[:success] = "<strong>Contacts Imported!</strong>"

    redirect_to contacts_path

  rescue => exception 
    flash[:error] = "There was a problem importing that contacts file.<br>
      <strong>#{exception.message}</strong><br>"

    redirect_to import_new_contacts_path
  end
end
```

#### Contact Model

**models/contact.rb**

```
def import import_file 
  File.foreach( import_file.path ).with_index do |line, index| 

    # Process each line.

    # For any errors just raise an error with a message like this: 
    #   raise "There is a duplicate in row #{index + 1}."
    # And your controller will redirect the user and show a flash message.

  end
end
```

Hope that helps!

Joshua

Comment: Just returning to think about this. I suppose it's not important to store the important file at all, even temporarily, because if something does go wrong with the import they'll have to re-import a new, fixed file anyway...

Answer (score 5):

In new.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag '/controller/method_name', :multipart => true do %>
   <label for="file">Upload text File</label> <%= file_field_tag "file" %>
   <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

In controller#method_name

```
uploaded_file = params[:file]
file_content = uploaded_file.read
puts file_content
```

see more for file upload in rails http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm
 [How to read whole file in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328495/how-to-read-whole-file-in-ruby)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This gives me an error: `undefined method 'read' for "myfile.txt":String`

Comment: Try it with an :accept option, e.g. file_field_tag 'file', :accept => 'text/html'

Comment: just install oen-uri using this command: $ sudo gem install open-uri

Comment: @novemberkilo This will only allow me to add .html files, and I get the same undefined method error with .html files. Suvankar, I'd already installed and required open-uri in that controller. Any idea what else I could do?

Comment: if file upload work properly it can uplaod any kind of file. did you missed 'multipart=> true'? see more to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm

Comment: $ [sudo] gem install carrierwave or add it in your gem file and then use bundle install. hope this will solve your problem