# Rails data migration—upload and process a folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, database-migration

I have hundreds of `.txt` files that need to be processed into a Rails db. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426135/how-to-upload-a-text-file-and-parse-contents-into-database-in-ror) talks about uploading and processing a single file, but I don't want to do that hundreds of times. Is there a way to upload a folder, then process each file within that folder?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know HTML5 Uploader supports uploading a directory but only Chrome has it implemented.
[example](https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/dnd/all_types_of_import.html)
[HTML5 Uploader](https://www.aurigma.com/docs/us8/uploading-folders-in-other-platforms-iuf.htm#setClientSide)

If you are the only one doing the uploading, I would zip the file and handle unzipping it and iterating through the files on the Rails side.  Note: if this will be a public interfece, you will have to be careful about sanitizing file names to prevent directory traversal attacks (e.g. '~/.ssh/authorized_keys').