# How to read JS file in my Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a scenario where I have to read `index.js` in my rails controller.

- index.js is located at `device/setup/index.js`
- the controller is located at `app/controllers/xxx_controller.rb`

Inside controller method, I have to get this `index.js` and I can't seem to read it with `File.open()` or `File.read()`. I tried relative path.

How can I read `index.js` in my controller?

Comment: What error did you get when you tried `File.open("device/setup/index.js")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read whole file in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328495/how-to-read-whole-file-in-ruby)

Comment: Reading file is no problem. I could do it after opening the correct file. Thanks to JP Silvashy for providing `Rails.root` solution. It solved my problem of getting to correct file directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Rails.root` to reference the root path of the app:

```
file = File.open(Rails.root.join('device', 'setup', 'index.js'))
```

Comment: Thanks JP Silvashy. 
`Rails.root` works like a charm. I can open the file now. Hope it will still work on production server.

Comment: Yes this will work on a production server as well! Good Luck!